# How to remove `_` from all file-names in a directory

Tags: files, rename, mv

In bash, I have an unzipped directory where I have many file names that start with `_`.

I'm pretty sure I can use `rename` or `mv` to simply remove the `_` prefix of each file that has it.

I try:

```
for file; do
    mv "$file" "${file//_/}"
done
```

But that doesn't have the effect I'd like. What command can I use to remove the `_` prefix from all files?

Comment: In exactly what way does this not have the effect you want?

Comment: Well, for one, `for file; do <stuff>; done` is a syntax error.

Comment: In once instance, it didn't remove any underscore prefixes. In another, it removed all underscores in every filename that starts with the `_` prefix

Comment: @DopeGhoti: `for x; do` is a shortcut for `for x in "$@"; do`, so, assuming that the code is in its own script file, this may work (if called as e.g. `script.sh _*`). I understand that's a lot off assumptions :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `for file; do` loops over the positional parameters, i.e. command line arguments to the script. Use `for file in *; do` to loop over the files in the directory (or `_*` to just take the ones with an underscore prefix.)

2) You can use `${file#_}` instead of `${file//_/}` to remove the underscore from the beginning of the filename. `${par#word}` specifically removes a part from the beginning, and it's a standard feature, unlike `${par/pat/repl}`. And of course `${file//_}` would remove *all* slashes (since you used a double-slash), not just the first one.

3) at least on Linux (GNU userland) and FreeBSD, you can use `mv -n` to ask it to not overwrite any files. Just in case.

So,

```
for file in _*; do
    mv -n -- "$file" "${file#_}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply with **`prename`** (Perl rename) command:

```
prename -n 's/^_//' _*
```

Answer (score 0):

You're awfully close:

```
for file in _*; do
    if ! [[ -f "${file/_/}" ]]; then
        mv "$file" "${file/_/}"
    else
        echo "Replacement for '$file' already exists; skipping.." 1>&2
    fi
done
```

Why `${file/_/}`?  Because you specified an underscore prefix.  So `_file_name.ext` will become `file_name.ext`.  With `${file//_/}`, `_file_name.ext` would become `filename.ext`.

Comment: I'm still new to bash ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed

```
for file in /some/path/*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed 's*_**g'`
    fi
done
```

Comment: `[ -e "$file" ]` tests if a file of that name exists (regardless of its type). But you know it exists, since you just generated the name from a pattern match.

Comment: @ilkkachu I was looking for -f. Wanted to know if it's a file and not a directory. My bad...